# Display particular data into a file

Tags: command-line, display

I'm new to Ubuntu and have been using it for a couple of weeks now. Recently I encountered a problem where in I had to display a particular data on to a file. Here is the output displayed on the terminal.

```
  Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2009-4028)
  CVSS Score is 6.8
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2009-4030)
  CVSS Score is 4.4
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2009-5026)
  CVSS Score is 6.8
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0075)
  CVSS Score is 1.7
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0087)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0101)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0102)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0112)
  CVSS Score is 3.5
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0113)
  CVSS Score is 5.5
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0114)
  CVSS Score is 3.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0115)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0116)
  CVSS Score is 4.9
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0118)
  CVSS Score is 4.9
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0119)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0120)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0484)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0485)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0490)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0492)
  CVSS Score is 2.1
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0540)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

  Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0553)
  CVSS Score is 7.5
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0574)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2012-0583)
  CVSS Score is 4.0
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

 Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2013-1492)
  CVSS Score is 7.5
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

  Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2013-1506)
  CVSS Score is 2.8
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)

Potential vulnerability found (CVE-2013-1521)
  CVSS Score is 6.5
  Full vulnerability match (incl. edition/language)
File "/usr/sbin/mysqld" (CPE = cpe:/a:mysql:mysql:5.1:::) on host glynis-desktop (key glynis-desktop)
```

I intend to display the Potential vulnerability found field and the corresponding score alone. There seems to be about 9995 entries and I would like to display all of them.

I have been using this command as of now

```
awk '/CVSS Score is/ < /Potential vulnerability found/' output.txt
```

but this seems to display only the name of the vulnerability or the score.
How do I display this in file(text,excel) such that all the vulnerability and the corresponding score willbe displayed.

Any help would be appreciated 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
grep -E "Potential vulnerability found|CVSS Score is" input_file
```

If you want to save the output in a text file, then use:

```
grep -E "Potential vulnerability found|CVSS Score is" input_file > output_file
```